# PHP is not updating my data while using POST method

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

Here, I am trying to update my data in SQL. Therefore, I have used 000webhost to update and fetch my data from mysql using php. I try to update and fetch data, but it always returning 'uploadAttendanceStatus() data: {"UCEC106":"1"}'. I want an output like this 'uploadAttendanceStatus() data: {"UCEC106":"15"}'.

This is the code which is use in flutter inside a Button Widget.

```
try {
        final response = await http.post(_url, body: {
          'roll_number': '1701305',
          'course_code': 'UCEC106',
          'dept': 'civil,
          'attendance': '15',
          'date': 'Jan 15',
        });

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var data = response.body;
          print('uploadAttendanceStatus() data: $data');
        } else {
          print('uploadAttendanceStatus.php: ${response.statusCode}');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Catch uploadAttendanceStatus.php: $e');
      }
```

This is the table, where I want to update.

```
______________________
roll_number | UCEC106 |
______________________
  1701305   |    0    |
______________________
```

This is the php code.

```
<?php

include "config.php";

$rollNumber = $_POST['roll_number'];
$courseCode = $_POST['course_code'];
$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$attendance = $_POST['attendance'];//I am not aware of php, but i think the problem is here....
$date = $_POST['date'];


if($dept!="" && $rollNumber!="" && $courseCode!="" && $attendance=!"" && $date!=""){
    if($dept=="civil"){
         $updateRequest = "UPDATE today_civil_attendance_sheet SET $courseCode=$attendance, date='$date' 
          WHERE roll_number=$rollNumber";
          $con->query($updateRequest);
       
              $getRequest = "SELECT $courseCode FROM today_civil_attendance_sheet WHERE 
              roll_number=$rollNumber";
              $result = $con->query($getRequest);
                  echo json_encode($result->fetch_assoc());       
 }else{
      //another dept..................................
 }   
}
?>
```

This is the output:
Expected Output: uploadAttendanceStatus() data: {"UCEC106":"15"}
Actual Output: uploadAttendanceStatus() data: {"UCEC106":"1"}

Also is there anyway adding that field, like adding 0+5=5. What is the query for that?

Comment: use print_r($_POST);  before "if($dept!="" && $rollNumber..." to see what you're getting

Comment: Using this, I was only able see what i post and this is the output .....(
I/flutter (15034):     [roll_number] => 1701035
I/flutter (15034):     [course_code] => UCEC106
I/flutter (15034):     [dept] => civil
I/flutter (15034):     [date] => January 20
I/flutter (15034):     [attendance] => 2
I/flutter (15034): )
I/flutter (15034): {"UCEC106":"1"}

Comment: @Dharman You are right but I don't know how to that.

Comment: You can learn here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. Actually, My problem was with the if statement

```
if($dept!="" && $rollNumber!="" && $courseCode!="" && $attendance=!"" && $date!="")
```

I have used `$attendance=!""` instead of `$attendance!=""`.